# How to open an OpenOffice document and scroll to a bookmark?

Tags: linux, command-line, openoffice

How to open an OpenOffice document and scroll to a bookmark or chosen page number? Can I do this with the command-line?

Answer (score 3):

You will likely need to look into the OpenOffice scripting facilities. Look at some of the [OpenOffice Macro Information by Andrew Pitonyak](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php). In his document "[Useful Macro Information](http://www.pitonyak.org/AndrewMacro.odt)" (.odt file link warning) pay attention to section 7.2.3 "You can move a cursor to a Bookmark anchor"

```
Dim oAnchor  'Bookmark anchor
  Dim oCursor  'Cursor at the left most range.
  Dim oMarks

  oMarks = ThisComponent.getBookmarks()
  oAnchor = oMarks.getByName("MyMark").getAnchor()
  oCursor = ThisComponent.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
  oCursor.gotoRange(oAnchor, False)
```